# How to manual recover a PV

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

according to the official docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/ with the “Retain” policy a PV can be manually recovered . What does that actually mean and is there a tool how I can read the data from that "retained" PV and write it into to another PV , or does it mean you can mount that volume manual in order to gain access ?

Answer (score 31):

The process to manually recover the volume is as below.

You can use the same PV to mount to different pod along with the data even after the PVC is deleted (PV must exist, will typically exist if the reclaim policy of storageclass is Retain)

Verify that PV is in released state. (ie no pvc has claimed it currently)

```sh
 ➜  ~ kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS     CLAIM                     STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-eae6acda-59c7-11e9-ab12-06151ee9837e   16Gi       RWO            Retain           Released   default/dhanvi-test-pvc   gp2                     52m
```

Edit the PV (`kubectl edit pv pvc-eae6acda-59c7-11e9-ab12-06151ee9837e`) and remove the spec.claimRef part. The PV claim would be unset like below.

```sh
 ➜  ~ kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-eae6acda-59c7-11e9-ab12-06151ee9837e   16Gi       RWO            Retain           Available           gp2                     57m
```

Then claim the PV using PVC as below.

```yaml
---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dhanvi-test-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 16Gi
  volumeName: "pvc-eae6acda-59c7-11e9-ab12-06151ee9837e"
```

Can be used in the pods as below.

```yaml
volumes:
- name: dhanvi-test-volume
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: dhanvi-test-pvc
```

Update: Volume cloning might help  https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/06/21/introducing-volume-cloning-alpha-for-kubernetes/

Comment: Your answer will probably prevent many people from getting fired! :D

Comment: Good to hear that :D

Comment: Absolutely!!! Must have saved quite a few peeps from flying out the window. Kudos!

Comment: Doesn't deleting the `claimRef` without manually assigning it to PVC is enough? In my case I only removed the Ref and recreated the deployment, and the new PVC bound the existing volume automatically. Is that expected?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin what's the reclaim policy for your storage class?

Comment: The policy `retain`

Comment: I am not sure of this specific edge case, you might want to create a separate question for it :)

Answer (score 9):

There are three reclaim policies which define what happens with the persistent volume after deletion of the bound volume claim

- Retain
- Delete
- Recycle

**Delete** means the persistent volume as well as the associated storage asset in the external infrastructure is deleted.

**Recycle** (deprecated) will clean up the volume rm -rf /thevolume/* and after that it will be available for new persistent volume claims.

**Retain** leaves persistent volume in state released which does not allow for new persistent volume claims to reclaim it. The whole reclaim process is manual. You need to delete the persistent volume yourself. You can backup the data from the storage asset and delete the data afterwards. Then you can either delete the storage asset or create a new persistent volume for this asset.

If you want to write the data to another persistent volume using Kubernetes you could use a Job to copy the data.

In that case make sure you use persistent volume access modes ROX - ReadOnlyMany or RWX - ReadWriteMany and start a Job running a container which claims the persistent volume to be backed-up using a selector and claim another destination backup volume. Then copy the data via the container.

Alternatively, you can do the backup outside Kubernetes. Your method does then depend on the type of storage asset you are using. E.g., if you are using NFS you could mount source and destination and copy the data via command line.

Both options I've framed are more or less manual backup strategy. If you aim for a more sophisticated backup strategy for production workloads you might have a look at [Stash - Backup for your disks for production workloads in Kubernetes](https://github.com/appscode/stash)

Comment: This is good answer. I've tested retainPolicy 'Delete' with Kubernetes on AWS - after removing PVC for volume it got deleted altogether from AWS console in EC2's EBS volume.

Comment: FYI the Recycle reclaim policy has been deprecated since at least v1.16; "Warning: The Recycle reclaim policy is deprecated. Instead, the recommended approach is to use dynamic provisioning" (https://v1-16.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic)

Comment: And here's a "primary" source of the Recycle policy deprecation info: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59060

Answer (score 9):

Like stated in the answer by Tummala Dhanvi, the `spec.claimRef` section has to be tackled with. While removing the whole `spec.claimRef` can be useful if you have only one PV, this will prove **very nasty** if you have multiple PVs to be "rescued".

The first step is to ensure the PV has the `Retain` reclaim policy **before deleting** the PVC. You can edit or patch the PV to achieve that

- `kubectl edit pv pvc-73e9252b-67ed-4350-bed0-7f27c92ce826`

  - find the `spec.persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` key
  - input `Retain` for its value
  - save & exit
- or, in one command `kubectl patch pv pvc-73e9252b-67ed-4350-bed0-7f27c92ce826 -p "{\"spec\":{\"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy\":\"Retain\"}}"`

Now you can delete the PVC(s) (either by using `helm` or otherwise) and the PV(s) will not be deleted.

To successfully re-mount a PV to the **desired pod** you have to edit the PV configuration once again, this time the `spec.claimRef` section. But do not delete the whole section. Instead, delete only the `resourceVersion` and `uid` keys. The resulting section would then look something like this

```
...
  capacity:
    storage: 16Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: database
    namespace: staging
  nodeAffinity:
...
```

Repeat this for all of your PVs and their status in the `kubectl get pv` output will be `Available` afterwards. By leaving the `spec.claimRef.name` and `spec.claimRef.namespace` keys intact, we ensured that a new PVC with the corresponding `spec` (`staging/database` in my case), will be bound to the exact PV it is supposed to.

Also, make sure your new claim does not specify a larger storage capacity than the PV actually has (it seems though that the new claims' capacity may be less than the existing PV's). If the new PVC claims a larger storage, a new PV will be created instead. Best to keep it the same.

To digress: If the `storageClass` you're using allows for volume resizing, you can resize it later; here it's explained how: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/

My experience with this was pretty stressful. I've had 6 PVs, thakfully in `Retain` mode. For some reason a new deployment rollout got stuck, two pods just wouldn't want to terminate. In the end I ended up with deleting the whole deployment (using `helm`), restarting the cluster nodes, and then redeploying anew. This caused 6 *new* PVs to be created!

I found this thread, and went on to delete the `spec.claimRef` of all the PVs. Deleting and deploying the installation once again resulted in the PVs being reused, but they were not mounted where they supposed to, the data was not there. After a good amount of digging, I figured out that the `database` volume was mounted to a RabbitMQ pod, `mongodb` was mounted to ElasticSearch etc.

It took me about a dozen times around, to get this right. Luckily, for me the mixed-up mounting of volumes did not destroy any of the original data. The pods initializations did not clean-out the volume, just wrote their stuff there.

Hope this saves some seriuos headaches out there!

Answer (score 3):

I found this question for slightly different reasons than the existing answers address, so I'll weigh in.

In my case I had a self-managed Microk8s cluster for dev and testing purposes with
**manual, local storage** (mounted path on one of the Nodes), like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
    name: pv-1
    labels:
        type: local
spec:
    storageClassName: manual
    capacity:
        storage: 50Gi
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
    hostPath:
        path: "/mnt/data-1"
```

There was also a PVC and a Deployment using this PV. Then I nuked the namespace where these resources lived by accident.

What I wanted to achieve is to recreate the whole namespace and have it use this PersistentVolume with the same data that was still present on the server.

**In my case of local, manual storage** all it took was just to delete the PV and create it again. Deleting the PV does NOT delete the actual data on the server (at least with the `Retain` policy). Recreating the PV with a mount into a path where data already exists also works fine - the data is just used.

Comment: Note this is not a HA solution (the app will go down together with the machine).