# Re-create PVC for existing PV

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

In GCP GKE:

1. I created a PVC
2. GCP auto-created the underlying PV
3. I edit PV to have Reclaim Policy Retain
4. I deleted the PVC (the PV does not get deleted)
5. I want to re-create a PVC which connects to the existing PV

Is this possible? Is there any other way to use the existing PV?

Comment: you will have to delete the pv and pvc together and then recreate

Comment: @garlicFrancium but then what's the point of Reclaim Policy Retain?

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55568289/3514300